# Get tag and sprint value from Jira using python

Tags: python-2.7, api, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Could you please help to get Tag and Sprint value for particular issue

```
import jira.client
from jira.client import JIRA

options = {'server': 'https://example.com', 'verify':False}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('user', 'password'))
issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('project=11372 AND SPRINT not in 
closedSprints() AND sprint not in futureSprints()')
for value in issues_in_project:
print value.key , value.fields.summary , value.fields.assignee , 
value.fields.reporter ,value.fields.updated ,value.fields.resolutiondate, 
value.fields.duedate, value.fields.labels,value.fields.tag
```

While running the python script , I got error

> DWD-9933 Loading and Validating Products username username 2018-04-02T23:27:07.000-0700 None 2018-04-06 [u'DW-Products']
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "jira_test.py", line 23, in 
>   print value.key , value.fields.summary , value.fields.assignee , value.fields.reporter ,value.fields.updated ,value.fields.resolutiondate, value.fields.duedate, value.fields.labels,value.fields.tag
>   AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'tag'

Please have a look once and  help me to achieve this

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standart attributes use `getattr` built-in method with `field` name (which is technically `id`).
Some fields can be custom and their `id` look something like this `customfield_15100`. Here is how to get `JSON` with all your fields info https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-find-id-for-custom-field-s-744522503.html.

So in your case, `tag` could be a custom field.

```
for value in issues_in_project:

   # standart field
   print(getattr(value.fields(), 'reporter'))
   print(getattr(value.fields(), 'summary'))

   # custom field
   print(getattr(value.fields(), 'customfield_15100'))
```